# Не розмовний варіант до розмовного "слинявчик"

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/slynjavchyk) знайшла лише статтю "слинявчик", однак із заувагою "*розмовне*".

> **СЛИНЯ́ВЧИК**, а, чол., ***розм***. Нагрудник для маленьких дітей з цупкої тканини або клейонки для захисту одежі від слини й забруднення.

Цікавить, *чи є ще не розмовне слово (літературне), що відповідало значенні "слинявчик"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)  як відповідник цього слова подають:

> Також **слинявчиком** називають **нагрудник** у маленьких дітей, який застосовується для тих же цілей.

(також трохи в іншому значенні):

> **Нагрудні серветки** (в українській мові їх зазвичай не називають слинявчиками), які використовуються під час прийому їжі, яка включає «складні» або «незручні» страви, як, наприклад, омари (лобстери).

В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghrudnyk):

> **НАГРУ́ДНИК**, а, чол.
>   1. Фартух або частина фартуха, яка надягається на груди для захисту їх від чого-небудь. На листках [альбома]манячили групи інституток, товаришок Ольги, в білих хвартушках і нагрудниках (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 558).

Отже, як відповідники до слова слинявчик можна вживати **нагрудник, нагрудна серветка.**